# Adding AxMicrosoftOffice.Interop.OWC11.AxSpreadsheet to a VB.net project

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio 2013 project with an Excel Spreadsheet.  Now I am trying to create a new project.  I have added the correct reference to Microsoft Office Web Components 11.  But when I look in the Toolbox, I can't find the spreadsheet anywhere.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  Boy, this is not intuitive.  To add the spreadsheet component, you need to display the Visual Studio Toolbox and then right click the Toolbox and choose "Choose Items...".  From the dialog box, you need to COM Components, and then scroll all the way down to "Microsoft Office Spreadsheet Component".